# Solution to integral problem associated with the Gold-Hoyle flux tube

Tags: integration

I have the following problem I'm trying to solve analytically.

For reference it is related to the Gold-Hoyle magnetic flux tube equations which are slightly modified.

In cylindrical co-ords I have a magnetic field

$B_r = \frac{f(r)}{1+b^2r^2}, B_{theta}=\frac{f(r)br}{1+b^2r^2}, Bz=0$

This magnetic field (Br,Btheta,Bz) has a Lorentz force JxB where J=curl(B).

Now if f(r) = 1. Then JxB is identically zero. This is the Gold hoyle flux tube.

If however, we don't make any assumptions about f(r), other than it's differentiable, we end up with

$(JxB)_r = \frac{-f(r)f'(r)}{1+b^2r^2}$

Now suppose I want to define a gas pressure profile such that grad(P)=JxB then in my cylindrical coordinates I have

$p(r) = p0 - \int{\frac{f(r)f'(r)}{1+b^2r^2}} dr$

Assuming I have analytic equations for f(r), f'(r), f''(r), e.g. it's a function like tanh(r). Is there a way to solve for p(r) without using the form for f?

UPDATE: Assuming I have to actually make an assumption on f(r). Let's say $f(r)=\tanh(r-r1)$

then

$(JxB)_r = -\frac{sech^2(r-r1)\tanh(r-r1)}{1+b^2r^2}$

and my required integral is

$P(r) = P0 - \int{\frac{sech^2(r-r1)\tanh(r-r1)}{1+b^2r^2}dr}$

and is this solve-able?

Thanks

Comment: Been here 3 years, why no mathjax??

Comment: Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Fixed equations in latex